# Why is NoProfile pwsh parameter considered safer?

Tags: powershell

I read that when using a Powershell script in a scheduled task, external command or shortcuts, to always use the `-NoProfile` parameter. This is because otherwise Powershell will load some other profile which will be dangerous since you wouldn't know the content and can produce unexpected behaviours.

What I don't understand is, to my knowledge, by default, Powershell will run the "Current User, Current Host" profile (if I don't state -NoProfile). Since it is one of the basic profile files, why would it, or any of the other files be considered dangerous? Is it not trusted?

Links I referred to:

[Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3)

[Link 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)

Comment: It is not because the protfile is 'dangerous' but may effect the default the default behavior of the shell, as it may contains some custom configs, or some configs make by some random progarm. This changes may make the expected result change or simply failed. So adding -NoProfile is recommended for scripts and shortcut to preserve the default behaviour of the shell.

Comment: Appart from the fact that it might slow down your PowerShell session to startup, there are some security concerns especially if you started it with **Run with the highest privileges**, See e.g. [`#17148` Profiles shouldn't unnoticeable shared through UAC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17148)

Comment: @TommyAu So is the default profile "NoProfile" or "Current User, Current Host"? If it is the latter, isn't CUCH by Windows? So there shoud not be any random configurations? Or can it be altered by users? Am I missing something?

Comment: NoProfile means that it will run no profile, while on other situation the file under "Current User,Current Host",etc will be run according to the situation.The profile file can be altered by users, it is use for **customize your environment and to add session-specific elements to every PowerShell session that you start.** so using NoProfile is a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two "dangers", and one of them is just a "it might not do what you want" danger:

1. If you or someone else has customized the relevant profile, it might effect the behavior in ways you don't expect. Think about all the things a profile allows you to change, and how that might effect and cmdlet or external program that you run.

   This is especially important if you are running a PowerShell command as part of a script which will be executed by a user you don't control. If you're writing code that will run on my machine and you call PowerShell, you should ask yourself in that moment: do I want the user to be able to change what this PowerShell invocation does through their profile? are the kinds of changes that a user could inject here likely to be intentional and correctly executing my user's preferences, or unintentional or likely to cause a bug in this code?
2. If you're trusting the profile, and your script runs with elevated privileges, the profile could become an exploitable privilege escalation vulnerability for a hacker who already has unprivileged code execution or even just an opportunity to modify the profile. This is the way that it can be "dangerous" in the more serious sense. It's not very likely, but security is about defense-in-depth - each individual step of a compromise  is usually either unlikely or feels like not a big deal or both. But if we leave the little steps available, over time the likelihood approached inevitability that hackers will chain them together into something that is a big deal.